# How to tell MVC for append ".input-validation-error" Class after its previous class in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css

I have a simple input tag in MVC based view,that bind from model and applied a regular expression validator on model's class, when user inputs an invalid data, MVC add another class named ".input-validation-error" problem is that my input tag already has a class name "col-6"
and MVC add another class before previous class ie: class=".input-validation-error col-6"

Is there any way to tell MVC to add .input-validation-error class after it's previous class?
class="col-6 .input-validation-error" where col-6 is previous class

I required this because in my responsive CSS a pseudo rule is applied that check class name that start with "col-" and apply some styles, [class^="col-"] { }

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be changing the CSS instead of JS, like this:

```
[class*="col-"] { }
```

This means that the pseudo-select is now apply on any class that contains `col-`